# Using callback to return data from dynamodb.getItem()

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm new to js - I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to return a value from an asynchronous operation using a callback.  This is my current iteration of my code and it is still returning 'test undefined'.  Can anyone check what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.  Any help appreciated.

```
        var test = this.getImgurClientId(function (data) {
            console.log(data.Item.ClientId.S);  //this has a value
            return data.Item.ClientId.S;
        });
        console.log('test ' + test); //prints 'test undefined'



      this.getImgurClientId = function(callback) {
        AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESSKEYID,
          secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESSKEYID,
          region: AWS_DYNAMODB_REGION
        });

        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

        //console.log(dynamodb);

        var params = {
          AttributesToGet: [
            "ClientId"
          ],
          TableName: 'ServiceProvider',
          Key: {
            "ProviderName": {
              "S": "Imgur"
            }
          }
        };

        dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            callback(err);
          } else {
//this query succeeds
            console.log("Query succeeded. " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            callback(data);

          }
        });

      }
```

Comment: Your assignment is breaking your asynchronicity. Lose the `var test=` part and just put the `this.getImgurClientId(function (data)` function call directly into the console.log statement.

Comment: Famous dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in your question, the call is asynchronous, so the only way to access your result is in the callback.

```
var test = this.getImgurClientId(function (data) {
            return data.Item.ClientId.S; //useless as the callback is asynchronous and is called in getImgurClient methdo
        });
        console.log('test ' + test); //the asynchronous call has not finished yet and you cannot wait for it
```

so:

```
var test = this.getImgurClientId(function (data) {
           data.Item.ClientId.S; //here is the only place where your datas are accessible
        });
```

For a more elegant way of handling asynchrous callbacks, you can take a look at the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise)

Comment: Could I set the value of a $rootScope variable within the call back so that I can save the value for use outside the callback?  I've been playing around with this approach but so far no luck.

Comment: You should work with `$q`'s promises or scope events (`$scope.$broadcast("event");` and `$scope.$on("event",callback);`) that's the cleanest way to handle that...

Comment: I'm sorry it's time for me to go home, I'll give you an example on promises tomorow if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I did get it working with callbacks, it is not pretty though.